# Controls bleeding within iframe on scroll in IE6

Tags: html, css, iframe, internet-explorer-6

I have content in an iframe, and when I scroll the main page (outside of the iframe), I get weird artifacts inside of the iframe, from the select and flash controls, in IE6.

How it should look (and does look in IE6 before scrolling the outer page):

[image: http://i34.tinypic.com/2b9r85.png]

How it looks after scrolling the outer page in IE6:

[image: http://i38.tinypic.com/2mg1qig.png]

It works fine in other browsers, including IE7+. If I load the content within the iframe directly, and scroll the page, it doesn't happen. It only happens when it's embedded in the iframe.

It seems as though certain controls within the iframe are scrolling with the outer page.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a native IE6 or one of the emulator-like apps like MultipleIE or Evolt? I've noticed occasional graphics problems with the emulators that don't occur on a native IE6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet may be to hide the iframe during the scroll event, or reflow the iframe after that event by resizing its width 1px smaller and then back to its original size. A reflow of the iframe should cause a redraw. You probably won't be able to make IE6 play 100% nice with iframe scrolling, etc.

Comment: Thanks Alex! Hiding and showing the iframe during the scroll event seems to fix it 95% of the time (occasionally see slight bleeding). I don't really mind if IE6 users have to deal with a little bit of frustration, but I'd like to keep this open for a while longer to see if there are any 100% solutions. Thanks again :)

Comment: No sweat! I'd love to see a 100% working version as well! So keep em comin'!